# Stringstream has null in between and has to copy in Char buffer

Tags: string, null, copy, char, buffer

I have Template string which is having NULL character in between the content. I have to copy whole string into a char* buffer.
Please help me how to copy?

Comment: As for me, it's not really fair to have that symbol in a NUL-terminated C string.

Comment: For the question: were I you, I'd store string length somehow, and specify that size when doing memcpy.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MYSTRINGSIZE 123
memcpy(dst, str.c_str(), MYSTRINGSIZE)
```

Try this.

Comment: str.c_str() will terminate with null char. it will not take after the null character.

Comment: example my string is "this\0demo"

Comment: str.c_str() will return you pointer to the beginning of your string. And memcpy will copy exactly str.size() bytes, not until first '\0' character.

Comment: str.c_str() reading till null character after that even though nLen specified, it is not considering the rest of the char after null. so memcpy fails in this case.
As your view, it its able to read the whole content, why should i do memcpy? directly i can assign to char buffer. Am i right?

Comment: str.c_str() do not read anything, it just returns pointer to a string. When your string have '\0', all functions that are iterating through string (strlen, strcpy and so on) will choke on that '\0'. So it's dagerous to use std::string methods to operate on it. And memcpy() do not look on what are you copying, it will just copy needed bytes.